# Basemap and proj get different projection result

Tags: matplotlib-basemap, proj

I am struggling to understand the projections using pyproj.

for now my question is to understand the results of projection operations

I have following coordinates that I project on x,y:

```
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
import pyproj

lon  = [3.383789, 5.822754]
lat = [48.920575, 53.72185]

# with Basemap
M = Basemap(projection='merc',ellps = 'WGS84')
q1, q2 = M(lon, lat)
for a,b in zip([x for x in q1], [x for x in q2]):
    print(a,b)
# with pyproj
from pyproj import Proj
p = Proj(proj='merc', ellps='WGS84',errcheck = True)
p1 = Proj(proj='latlong', datum='WGS84',errcheck = True)
print(p(3.383789, 48.920575), p(5.822754, 53.72185))
print(p1(3.383789, 48.920575), p1(5.822754, 53.72185))
```

20414190.011221122 65799915.8523339
20685694.35308374 66653928.94763097
(376681.6684318804, 6229168.979819128) (648186.0102944968, 7083182.075116195)
(0.0590582592427664, 0.8538251057188251) (0.10162622883366988, 0.9376231627625158)

why are the results different while I use the same projections parameters
as a newbie in geospatial data processing I apologize in advance for a question which may be trivial

Answer (score 0):

For Mercator projection, Basemap uses the origin of the grid coordinate system at lower-left extent of the computable values. With your code, the values can be computed as

```
M(0, 0, inverse=True)
# output: (-180.0, -89.98999999999992)
```

If you compute projection coordinates for (long=0, lat=0) and assign the values to (x0, y0). You get the shifts in coordinates (x0, y0) that make its projection coordinates different from standard values (0,0 at center of the map).

```
lon0, lat0 = 0, 0
x0, y0 = M(lon0, lat0)
# x0=20015077.371242613, y0=59546805.8807
```

For a test point at (long=3.383789, lat=48.920575),

```
lon1 = 3.383789
lat1 = 48.920575
x1, y1 = M(lon1, lat1)
```

with the coordinate shifts applied, the result is

```
print(x1-x0, y1-y0)
# output: (376259.9924608879, 6254386.049398325)
```

when compare with the values from `pyproj`

```
p0 = Proj(proj='merc', ellps='WGS84', errcheck = True)
print(p0(lon1, lat1))
# output (376681.6684318804, 6229168.979819128)
```

they are quite agree but not close. For small scale map plotting, you can't see the discrepancies on the maps.